# Keyboard Maestro interfering with control-tab action in browsers - how to disable?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, shortcut

I've just purchased Keyboard Maestro, and now when I am in a browser and click control-tab, I can no longer advance through the open tabs of the browser the way I did before. That key combination must be used in KM to do something, and that's pre-empting the system shortcut.

How can I find out what action is attached to that keystroke in KM (so I can either change it or disable it)?

Comment: Are you using Keyboard Maestro 6? According to http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/tour.html ctrl + tab is for windows switcher. I don't have keyboard maestro, but if you can disable the window switcher, that will fix it. Alternatively, follow http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1439459 to *re-replace* that shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Keyboard Maestro 6? According to their [website](http://keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/6/tour.html), <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> is for windows switcher.

I don't have keyboard maestro, but if you can disable the window switcher, that will fix it.

Alternatively, follow [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1439459) to *re-replace* that shortcut. I'll copy and paste that here, with a few differences for your case:

> Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts
>
> Then, click the "+" button. Select **your browser** as the Application
>   on the Window that pops up. Type **Select Previous Tab**, or whatever
>   it says under Window > Select *something* tab. in the 'Menu Title'
>   field. Then, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to set the shortcut
>   and click 'Add' to save.

Answer (score 7):

Open Maestro Switcher

All Macros -> Activate Window Swicher

[image: Window Switcher]

And you can change or remove  it from there. (click at "-" at the bottom)